# webform records need to csv files and file specific email

Tags: php, arrays, drupal

I cant stored data CSV in file

I can Load the data but I cant stored the data in the CSV files and stored the file in the specific folder My requirement was to load the web form details and send the email to specific users. I can able to download the CSV file but I can't store the details in CSV file

```
  function webform_email_menu() {
        $items = array();
         $items['webform_email'] = array(
            'title'             =>  'Webform Email',  //page title
            'description'       =>  'Webform Information',  //description show when mouse hover on link
            'page callback'     =>  'webform_list',  //callback function which is invoked when menu item is called.
            'access callback'   =>  true,  //any user can access this page
           );
         return $items;
    }



function webform_list() {
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.export');
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.components');
    module_load_include('inc', 'webform', 'includes/webform.submissions');  
    $submissions = webform_get_submissions(125);
echo "installation Type,Date of Purchase,Date of Install    ,Outdoor Unit Model,Outdoor Unit Serial,Indoor Unit 1 Model,Indoor Unit 1 Serial,Indoor Unit 2 Model,Indoor Unit 2 Serial,Indoor Unit 3 Model,Indoor Unit 3 Serial,Indoor Unit 4 Model,Indoor Unit 4 Serial,Indoor Unit 5 Model,Indoor Unit 5 Serial,Indoor Unit 6 Model,Indoor Unit 6 Serial,Indoor Unit 7 Model,Indoor Unit 7 Serial,Indoor Unit 8 Model,Indoor Unit 8 Serial,Indoor Unit 9 Model,Indoor Unit 9 Serial,Owner First Name,Owner Last Name,Installation Address 1,Installation Address 2,City,State/Province,Zip/Postal Code,Country ,Owner Phone Number,Owner Email,Contractor Information,Contractor Name,Contractor Address 1 ,Contractor Address 2,City,State/Province,Zip/Postal Code,Country,Contractor Phone Number,Contractor Email,Distributor Name,Distributor Address 1,Distributor Address 2,City,State/Province,Zip/Postal Code,Country,TAC,Privacy Statement\n";
   $surveycomponents = db_select('webform_component')
     ->fields('webform_component')
     ->condition('nid', 125)
     ->orderBy('weight')
     ->orderBy('name')
     ->execute()
     ->fetchAllAssoc('cid', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count =0;
$i=2;
   foreach ($submissions as &$submission) {
       $submission_value=$submission->data;
       $i=0;
       foreach($submission_value as $submissionvalue){
            $numItems = count($submission_value);
            if(++$i === $numItems) {
                echo $csv_export="\n";
            }else{
                echo $csv_export=$submissionvalue[0].',';
            }
       }
    }

        $file_open = fopen('sites/default/files/csv/csvfile.csv', "a");
        file_put_contents("sites/default/files/csv/csvfile.csv", $csv_export);
    $csv_handler = fopen ('sites/default/files/csv/csvfile.csv','w');
    fwrite ($csv_handler,$csv_export);
    fclose ($csv_handler);

}
```

My input like multidimensional array

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => XXXXX
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2017-06-02
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2017-06-16
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [19] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [21] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [23] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [24] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test@gmail.com
                    )

                [26] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [27] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [28] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [29] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [30] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ST
                    )

                [31] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 47834
                    )

                [32] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SH
                    )

                [33] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test@gmail.com
                    )

                [35] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [36] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [37] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [38] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 1
                    )

                [39] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => DJ
                    )

                [40] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0225
                    )

                [41] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => IN
                    )

                [42] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => yes
                    )

                [43] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [44] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [45] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [46] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [47] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [48] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [49] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [50] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [51] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [52] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [53] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [54] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (000) 123-4567
                    )

                [55] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (000) 123-4567
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => XXXXX
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2017-06-02
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2017-06-16
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [19] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [21] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [23] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [24] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test@gmail.com
                    )

                [26] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [27] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [28] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [29] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [30] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ST
                    )

                [31] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 47834
                    )

                [32] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SH
                    )

                [33] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test@gmail.com
                    )

                [35] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [36] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [37] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [38] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 2
                    )

                [39] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => DJ
                    )

                [40] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0225
                    )

                [41] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => IN
                    )

                [42] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => yes
                    )

                [43] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [44] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [45] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [46] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [47] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [48] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [49] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [50] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [51] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [52] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [53] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [54] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (000) 123-4567
                    )

                [55] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (000) 123-4567
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => XXXXX
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2017-06-02
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2017-06-16
                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [16] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [17] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [18] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [19] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [20] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [21] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [22] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [23] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [24] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test@gmail.com
                    )

                [26] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [27] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [28] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [29] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [30] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => ST
                    )

                [31] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 47834
                    )

                [32] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SH
                    )

                [33] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => test@gmail.com
                    )

                [35] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [36] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [37] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [38] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Tested Value 3
                    )

                [39] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => DJ
                    )

                [40] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 0225
                    )

                [41] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => IN
                    )

                [42] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => yes
                    )

                [43] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [44] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [45] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [46] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [47] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [48] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [49] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [50] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [51] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [52] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [53] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 
                    )

                [54] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (000) 123-4567
                    )

                [55] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => (000) 123-4567
                    )

            )
    )
```

Comment: Please go read [ask], and then edit your question to contain a _proper_ problem description - _“I can’t”_ isn’t one. Describe what specific issue you are having, what you tried to implement, and where/how exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: It might just be the nonsense combination of fopen and file_put_contents though, I guess … You don’t use fopen with file_put_contents or file_get_contents.

Comment: thanks for your reply
Array details need to store in csv file. I can create the file but due to the multiarray
data not store in file.
that my problem

Comment: I checked all the other answers. The problem was my input. If you see the input you can get the clarity